# Como usar a API do GitHub no ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, github

Boa tarde.

gostaria de saber como trabalhar com API do gitHub no ASP.NET.
Nunca trabalhei com APIs antes.

**PS. Não posso utilizar o octokit**

Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Obrigado

Comment: Por que não pode usar o Octokit? Ela é a principal API.

Comment: É uma seleção então não posso usar o Octokit. Devo utilizar apenas a api Aberta (REST)

Comment: O que é "seleção"? [Estamos falando desta API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)?

Comment: Não no, desculpe se confundi.. Não posso utilizar porque estou participando de uma seleção para desenvolvedor.

Comment: Está participando de um processo seletivo. Acho que passei pelo mesmo que o seu! Haha - vou ver se respondo dando só o caminho das pedras...

Answer (score 2):

## TLDR;

Use requisições HTTP normais para acessar a API, lendo os dados do JSON de retorno.

## Um Pouco de Background

A API do GitHub é uma API `RESTful`, o que basicamente quer dizer que seus dados são acessíveis por requisições HTTP comuns,  sem utilizar de protocolos extras para a leitura deles (como o `SOAP`). Uma API REST se baseia no uso correto do protocolo HTTP, usando seus métodos para o que realmente foram criados:

- `GET` - **pegar** conteúdo da API
- `POST` - **introduzir** conteúdo na API
- `PUT` - **atualizar** conteúdo na API
- `DELETE` - **remover** conteúdo da API

A especificação do REST também introduziu o termo recurso, que nada mais são do que o que a API expõe (users, repos, etc) e o melhor uso das [URIs](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI) (Uniform Resource Identifier), para identificar recursos específicos (URLs são URIs).

## A Resposta

Não vou dar a resposta. Como você está participando de um processo seletivo (e outras pessoas caem nessa resposta na mesma situação), isso não seria justo; vou apenas explicar como funciona, o que fazer, mas sem código.

Como disse, APIs REST podem ser consumidas através de requisições HTTP normais (tipo a que você faz do browser pra acessar qualquer página web). Por isso, você pode utilizar a classe [HttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) para consumir a API. Alterando a URL e o método das requisições você consegue fazer tudo que precisa pra extrair dados da API.

Depois de conseguir trazer os dados, você vai receber uma string, isso é um JSON. É um modo de representar dados (uma instância de uma classe com todas as suas propriedades, por exemplo) por meio de string, para uma troca de dados mais simples. Para transformar esse JSON em algo que você possa utilizar, você pode usar a biblioteca [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (antigo `Newtonsoft.Json`), para fazer com que ele vire um objeto C# normal.

É basicamente isso! Depois você vai ter tudo o que precisa. Pesquise sobre esses caras que tem muito tutorial pela internet afora. Caso não tenha entendido alguma coisa, é só falar.